# save image from Uri and setimageview when the application start

Tags: android, imageview, sharedpreferences

```
  public class OneFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment implements DialogClickListener {





    @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    context = inflater.getContext();
    viewstart = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one_before_start,           container, false);
     image=(CircularImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imageview1);
     String pathe=getSharedPreferences_Str(keyimage);
     Uri my=  Uri.parse(pathe);
     Log.d("tag",pathe );

     Log.d("tag", "loula" + my.toString());
     image.setImageURI(my);


     image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                                  @Override
                                  public void onClick(View v) {
                                      buldershow(v.getContext());
                                  }
                              }
     );


     public void onSelectFromGalleryResult(Intent data)//fih chek ??
{
    Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();

    String[] projection = {MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA};
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(selectedImageUri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String selectedImagePath = cursor.getString(column_index);
    String  s=selectedImageUri.toString();
    save_SharedPreferences(keyimage, s);

    Log.d("tag", "thnya" + selectedImageUri.toString());

    Uri m=Uri.parse(s);
    image.setImageURI(m);
}


    public void buldershow(Context context){


final CharSequence[] items = {"Choose from Library",
        "Cancel"};

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {

        if (items[item].equals("Choose from Library")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(
                    Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"),
                    1);//nbre de fichier a selctione
        } else if (items[item].equals("Cancel")) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
});
builder.show();
  }


 @Override
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)     {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == 1) {

            onSelectFromGalleryResult(data);

        }
    }
}
```

when i select image from gallery  imageview changed  from the  void onSelectFromGalleryResult but when the application starts again the image view comes empty   void oncreatview :( and the url is the same :(

[image: Image 1 added]

[image: Image 2 added]

Comment: the imageview changed in void onSelectFromGalleryResult but when the application starts again the image view comes empty

Comment: Please add more details regarding your problem. Try to be as specific as possible.

Comment: i add more details can i help me plz  and thanks  :D

Comment: Add code for `getSharedPreferences_Str()` and `save_SharedPreferences()`

Comment: public void save_SharedPreferences(String Key , String val){
        preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putString(Key, val);
        editor.commit();

    }

Comment: public String getSharedPreferences_Str(String key){

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        String  data = sharedPreferences.getString(key, " ") ;
        return data;
    }